# Is it more secure to put data access in a web service rather than a class within the current project?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

We have a few projects that we put all the data access in a separate web service project and the parent project will call the web service for everything data related. The web service will only accept connections from the web project server. My assumption is that the web service would be less susceptible to intrusion this way. I'm not really sure this is correct.

Is this more secure than just putting the data access in a class or dll within the parent project?

NOTE
Developers above me made this decision.

Comment: That all depends on how well the webservices have been setup.

Comment: @andrew, do you mean as far as firewall and access privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that as an effective way of securing your database.  Of all the various ways that exist to protect your data layer, I don't think that moving calls from a class library to a web service is an effective way to protect yourself.

A better approach would be to make sure that you use parameterized queries or stored procedures to prevent SQL injection, and limit the privileges of your logins to only the operations that they need to perform.

However, there would be other arguments for having data access in a separate web service... such as re-usability, or a service-oriented architecture.  If the same data access layer is needed from a variety of projects on multiple servers, by having the web service you wouldn't need to have the same class library duplicated all over the place... which would cause you to worry about which project has which version of your data access layer.

So, more secure? I don't think so... Other benefits? Probably...

Comment: Most of the time, I feel like it's more trouble than it's worth. Every deployment takes twice as long and twice as many places for errors.

Comment: Yea... there has to be a balance between the complexity of the solution, and the need for that complexity (YAGNI).  If you're not seeing the benefits from the separate web service, it could be a case of over-engineering; definitely wouldn't be the first time that has happened...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes

Longer answer: My assumption is that the web server that is exposing the services is behind its own firewall.  Doing it this way insulates the database from intrusion by forcing hackers to go through another layer if they were able to compromise your application servers.  Since the database connection strings do not exist on the app server, and a firewall prevents direct connections from that server to the database, the hackers would need to somehow puncture that firewall and gain access to the server that is hosting your data services.

Now, I also assume that the web services are not simply exposing methods like

```
execute(string sqlCommand)
```

if that's the case, then this solution might actually *less* secure than simply using a database without the web services.  For this solution to truly be more secure you would want to create operation-specific methods on the web service server.

Comment: I actually snorted when I read the part about execute(string sqlCommand). Fortunately, we aren't doing anything that insane. They're all just methods that return booleans, datasets, and strings. Basically, you're saying that it justs adds more deadbolts to your door that the hacker will need to pick as well?

Answer (score 1):

A DLL can't be accessed and executed from the Web, so far as I know. A Web service can. If that's true, the class library referenced by a Web project (or even a Web Service) is more secure than a Web service encapsulating that logic directly.

Further, there's the whole notion of Separation of Concerns. In my mind, data access logic belongs on a separate tier, completely separate from business logic. In a well designed architecture, Web services expose discrete methods that represent business transactions--not necessarily data transactions. Business transactions encapsulate one or more data transactions, which are represented by separate classes that encapsulate the data access logic and provide the security to ensure that SQL injection never occurs.

Others, naturally, may disagree. We're developers. It's our nature to disagree. :)